# Python: Set the maximum of a function and loop around to find the maximum of the next value in an array

Tags: python, arrays, function, loops

I am trying to find the maximum of function when I give it a range of values and then put that same value into an array for later use. In this case I have 2 parameters, one being the x and the other the theta. My issue is that it isn't looping around to the next x value in the list. Is there a way to make it loop around and and set the maximum into an array?

```
import sympy.mpmath as mp 
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sc
from scipy.optimize import fmin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#INPUT
c = 299792458. #speed of light
f = 300e6 #frequency
lmda = c/f #lambda
C = 0.5772 #Euler's constant

def E(x):

      i = [] #creates an empty list

      for z in x:

           def kl(x):
           return (2*np.pi/lmda)*x*lmda/2

           def U(theta):
                 u = (np.cos(kl(z)*np.cos(theta))-np.cos(kl(z)))/np.sin(theta)
           return u

           theta = np.linspace(0.0001,np.pi,1000)
           E_max = fmin(lambda theta: -U(theta), 0)

           i+=[E_max]

return np.array(i)

def Denom(x):

y = [] #creates an array

for z in x:

    def kl(x):
        return (2*np.pi/lmda)*x*lmda

    def Integrand(x):
        f =np.abs( mp.ci(kl(x)) + 0.5*np.sin(kl(x))*(mp.si(2*kl(x))-2*mp.si(kl(x))) + 0.5*np.cos(kl(x))*(2*mp.ci(kl(x)) - mp.ci(2*kl(x))))
        return f

    PWR_tot = Integrand(z)
    y+=[PWR_tot]

return np.array(y)


x = np.linspace(0.0001,5.,1000)

Directivity = E(x)/Demon(x)

plt.plot(x,Directivity)
plt.ylim(ymin = 0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: your return statements are not indented to live in the functions they return from.  Also you define kl (twice!?), Integrand, and U inside loops. Define them above the loop, and if needed call them in the loop

Comment: You have too many indentation problems.  That code won't run.  Look at it carefully, and fix up the indentations  E() and Denom() must have their code suite indented.  Your returns need to be indented, your function defs inside functions are odd and should be removed and put in the main block of code

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "indented to live in the function"?

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your code is not correct, that is why you don't get any result. First, you define functions within for loops. This does not yield an error, but what you actually want to do is define the function earlier and then call it in the for loop, as such:

```
def myfunction(x):
  return x+ 3

for y in range(0,4):
  print( myfunction(y) )
```

Also notice that the return statement has to be indented in order to belong to the function, as joel goldstick pointed out. Otherwise, the function will return nothing. The same holds for every statement in your E(x) function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the elaboration you asked for above:

Your code:

```
def E(x):

i = [] #creates an empty list

for z in x:

    def kl(x):
        return (2*np.pi/lmda)*x*lmda/2

    def U(theta):
        u = (np.cos(kl(z)*np.cos(theta))-np.cos(kl(z)))/np.sin(theta)
        return u

    theta = np.linspace(0.0001,np.pi,1000)
    E_max = fmin(lambda theta: -U(theta), 0)

    i+=[E_max]

return np.array(i)
```

Your code with some edits to fix indentation issues:

```
def kl(x):
    return (2*np.pi/lmda)*x*lmda/2

def U(theta):
    u = (np.cos(kl(z)*np.cos(theta))-np.cos(kl(z)))/np.sin(theta)
    return u


def E(x):

    i = [] #creates an empty list

    for z in x:
        theta = np.linspace(0.0001,np.pi,1000)
        E_max = fmin(lambda theta: -U(theta), 0)

        i+=[E_max]   # this line looks weird is E_max an list?
        #perhaps:
        i.append(E_max)

    return np.array(i)
```

That is just the top part of your code.  The bottom part needs similar treatment.  Also sprinkle in some print statements in your loops to see if they are doing what you think they should